# Пустые ревизии метки

Tags: поддержка, метки, описание-метки

Смотрю вот на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/413144/revisions и думаю, что что-то не так.

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И что вас смущает? У метки [ajax](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax) действительно нет полного описания. 1 апреля метка была создана и Дух Сообщества автоматически создал для нее пустое описание. Краткое описание тоже было создано, но оно с тех пор получило две правки.

Похоже, это вопрос из разряда «Возвращать `null` или `""`». Хранить пустое описание метки в базе данных достаточно просто, а вот хранить там null — неудобно, его придется каждый раз проверять и заменять на `""`.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/413145/revisions

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]